# xltm file opens when I run a macro

Tags: excel

I have a macro enabled template (trainings.xltm file). I create a new Excel workbook from that template (trainings1). That works fine. However, when I run a macro in trainings1, that macro is executed but opens trainings.xltm. If I save trainings1 as 07112017.xlsm and run a macro in that file, the trainings.xltm is opened, too. So there is no difference between the newly created file and a saved file.
I don't want trainings.xltm to open automatically every time i run a macro. How can I stop that?
I have the macros in the ribbon, I have checked they point to the .xlsm file.

Any ideas are very welcome.

Regards,

Michael

Comment: Developer tab>Add-Ins>Activate/Deactivate trainings.xltm

Comment: Mo, Thank you, but that doesn't work. There is no AddIn.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The ribbon is global, I think that's why the newly created file always opens the template.
I created a custom ui file using the office-ribbonx-editor (https://github.com/fernandreu/office-ribbonx-editor) from Fernando Andreu.
Next I deleted my macros from the ribbon. Now the new file does not open the template. As a positive side effect, my ribbon is only visible in files created from that template and not in other files. They wouldn't work there anyway.